# Event Of Specific BT device Has Connected Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I want to know when specific BT device has connected.

What I tried is, `BroadcastReceiver` listen to `ACL_CONNECTED`.

But it works only when app is running. 
When I stop app, I don't get the event.

[I read that Android exempted this event](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html) But still doesn`t work.

Do you know another solution?

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".recivers.BTReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

SLOVED!

1. I added

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml`

2. Call `startForegroundService` instead `startService`. (Even you call `startForeground` within `onStartCommand`)